# How to find the .php link for a website in order to get its cookies using wget

Tags: php, cookies, wget

I am trying to access the files from a webpage that requires a login using wget and I am having some trouble.

I am using the standard way described in the manual to get and use the cookies:

## Log in to the server.  This only needs to be done once.

```
`wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
 --keep-session-cookies \
 --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
 --delete-after \
 http://server.com/auth.php`
```

## Now grab the page or pages we care about.

```
`wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
 http://server.com/interesting/article.php`
```

Whenever I download the files, however, it always downloads the code for accessing a webpage where I need to login. I think the issue is that I am using the wrong link, since the link I use is not a php link but, rather, the http link found at the top in the search bar. So, how do I find the php link I need to use in order to get and use the cookies I find?

Comment: `article.php` is a PHP page. Are you talking about something else?

Comment: The page may use JavaScript to implement its download options. You need to read the script and find the script it sends to.